# Use Facebook Graph Api to get info about comment?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get info (text and uid) from comments in my application.

`https://graph.facebook.com/commentID`

I think I need my apps access token to get the comment info. How do I get it and echo/alert with comment's info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to request the user to allow your application and then use the access token you get in the request to the Graph API...

the allow of the application can be done in both server side or Javascript (I prefer JS)

an example for how to allow an application and invoke a graph api call can be found in the facebook developers js sdk documentation below:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/

```
function loginAndGetData(){
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
           if(response.status=="connected"){
                FB.Api("commentID",onGotData);
           } else {
                FB.Login(function(response){
                    if(response.status=="connected"){
                         FB.Api("commentID",onGotData);
                    }
                });
           }
    });
}

function onGotData(data){
    console.log(data)
}
```

Comment: Why do I need to request the user to allow the application? I know the comment's ID and own the application. Can't I see the commenters UID without a need for login?

Comment: try getting the data of the comments using the application's access token - the token can be generated by concatenating the application id and application secret with an "|" between. `$access_token=APP_ID."|".APP_SECRET_KEY;`

Comment: Great, I should be able to get it without authenticating the user then right? I'm going to: `https://graph.facebook.com/10150692305296360/?access_token=appid|secretkey` but I'm still getting false. I should be able to see the info if the comment was made in my URL right?

Comment: so probebly this is not the application that sent that comment, you will have to have a valid access token... whose post is it? where did it came from? Facebook Comments Social Plugin? page post? photo?...

Comment: I don't know who made the comment. I'm using Facebook Comments Social Plugin. Isn't it possible to know the commenters info for the APP administrator?

Comment: I'm testing it on "lujanventas.com/test.php". also using `<fb:comments-count href=lujanventas.com/test.php/>` gives me '0' as the number of comments.

Comment: this is the list of comments:
https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=http://lujanventas.com/test.php

and this is an example for one of the comments:
https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=10150692213226360_22324069

Comment: in the `fb:comments-count` you see 0 comments because you didn't pass `http://` in the begining of the `href` attribute

Comment: Nope still doesn't work. I tried with http and without I'll submit it as a questin if it still doesn't work. However my original problem is more than solved. Thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10673/discussion-between-liso22-and-yaron-uliel)